# Android retrofit: 400 bad request response code

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

So I'm still in the process of learning android dev and I'm currently working on an app which is supposed to show students their grades. Right now I am stuck at getting login to a service from which grades are collected. For that process I am using https://eduo-ocjene-docs.vercel.app/ api (documentation is in Croatian).
This is what curl request for logging in looks like:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://ocjene.eduo.help/api/login' \--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \--data-raw '{    "username":"ivan.horvat@skole.hr", "password":"ivanovPassword123"}'
```

Here are screenshots of what I have tried until now

Here is how I build retrofit

```kotlin
object ApiModule {

    private const val BASE_URL = "https://ocjene.eduo.help/"

    lateinit var retrofit: EdnevnikApiService

    private val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }

    fun initRetrofit() {
        val okhttp = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }).build()

        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
            .client(okhttp).build().create(EdnevnikApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

The login method

```kotlin
interface EdnevnikApiService {

    @HTTP(method = "get", path = "/api/login", hasBody = true)
    fun login(@Body request: LoginRequest): Call<LoginResponse>

}
```

This is what happens when the login button is clicked

```kotlin
fun onLoginButtonClicked(email: String, password: String) {
    val request = LoginRequest(email, password)
    ApiModule.retrofit.login(request).enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
            loginResultLiveData.value = response.isSuccessful
            val body = response.body()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            loginResultLiveData.value = false
        }

    })
}
```

and this is what kotlin request and kotlin response data classes look like

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class LoginRequest(
    @SerialName("username") val username: String,
    @SerialName("password") val password: String,
)
```

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class LoginResponse(
    @SerialName("LoginSuccessful") val isSuccessful: Boolean,
)
```

Oh and this is what I get from the interceptor when I send the request
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is server is responding with `400 Bad Request` due to **unsupported method type**. When I replaced `method = "get"` with `method = "GET"` in your sample code, I received:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
```

which makes sense. Luckily, the `/login` API you shared works with `POST` method type, so you can try using:

```
@HTTP(method = "POST", path = "/api/login", hasBody = true,)
```

I checked at my end and I received the following response:

```
<-- 200 https://ocjene.eduo.help/api/login (1390ms)
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
set-cookie: epicCookie=f69fbd6d4f10b5cc38e038b5da0843b356776c58c4fb32aed24dbcc49026778724bc25e21448c05a29df9f4b5558b254011fb3f8a992710f9901f23c53be5eaadaa799f3f5ac9e18de191bed02ef3e96030b83042ee8392755b03dd785edca6a;
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
etag: "bkrbkvg0eo6c"
vary: Accept-Encoding
date: Thu, 10 Nov 2022 03:07:08 GMT
server: Fly/b1863e2e7 (2022-11-09)
via: 2 fly.io
fly-request-id: 01GHFR2T56X9K0GFN3DH1Z9JYV-sin
{"LoginSuccessful":false,"token":"f69fbd6d4f10b5cc38e038b5da0843b356776c58c4fb32aed24dbcc49026778724bc25e21448c05a29df9f4b5558b254011fb3f8a992710f9901f23c53be5eaadaa799f3f5ac9e18de191bed02ef3e96030b83042ee8392755b03dd785edca6a"}
<-- END HTTP (228-byte body)
```

Comment: Yeah retrofit doesn't really like body in get requests, but I changed the method to post and everything works now. Got a successful login. Thank you so much for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
object ApiModule {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://ocjene.eduo.help/"
    lateinit var retrofit: EdnevnikApiService
    private val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
    fun initRetrofit() {
        val okhttp = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }).build()
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
            .client(okhttp).build().create(EdnevnikApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).